# numpy ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

```
thetaU = np.linalg.inv(np.linalg.inv(theta) + theta2_input**(-1)*np.transpose(X_test[i]) * X_test[i])
```

When I execute the following inside one of my functions.. I get the following error:

```
ValueError:  operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,100) (100,2)
```

I'm kind of new to Python and would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: Identify the operation, and the arrays that are causing the problem.  Which arrays have these two shapes?  Is that what you expect?  Maybe you don't need the `transpose`? Or maybe you are using the wrong multiply.  We can't really tell from just reading your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In NumPy, operator `*` does *not* represent matrix multiplication. It multiplies two arrays element-wise. Replace it with `np.matmul()` or `np.dot()`:

```
np.matmul(np.transpose(X_test[i]), X_test[i]))
```