# ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,6) (6,2)

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to calculate the diffenrece between identity matrix and an array then multiply each other with one transpose of the other but I'm getting this error

```
X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1.9], [-3, -2], [1.2, 1.5], [2.3, -1], [4.2, 7]])
s = np.eye(len(X), 2)
t_1 = (s - X).T
t_2 = (s - X)
prod = t_1 * t_2
```

Comment: Did you mean `@` instead of `*`? The former performs matrix multiplication, whereas the latter performs hadamard product, i.e., elementwise multiplication.

Comment: ok forget the second part of the question but the first part as you suggested it 's giving  None ... I want to solve
(I - X) (I -X).T

Comment: it's working thnx

Answer (score 0):

According to similar question asked in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60584068/18142235 you were probably confused about the matrix multiplication operand which is np.dot not * in python, so:

```
X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1.9], [-3, -2], [1.2, 1.5], [2.3, -1], [4.2, 7]])
s = np.eye(len(X), 2)
t_1 = (s - X).T
t_2 = (s - X)
prod = np.dot(t_1 , t_2 )
```